# CloudFront ErrorConfigurations not being created

Tags: .net, amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudfront, aws-cdk

I'm using AWS CDK .NET to build up and deploy a stack that has a S3 Bucket and a CloudFront distribution in it.

Everything builds up and deploys without an error, but what I noticed is that the Custom Error Responses do not get created at all.

The distribution is there and looks good, but the errors are not there.

```
            CloudFrontWebDistributionProps webDistributionProps = new CloudFrontWebDistributionProps
            {
                OriginConfigs = originConfigs,
                DefaultRootObject = "index.html",
                HttpVersion = HttpVersion.HTTP2,
                ViewerProtocolPolicy = ViewerProtocolPolicy.REDIRECT_TO_HTTPS,
                ErrorConfigurations = new[]{
                     new CustomErrorResponseProperty{
                         ErrorCode = 403,
                         ErrorCachingMinTtl = 30,
                         ResponseCode = 200,
                         ResponsePagePath = "/index.html"
                     },
                     new CustomErrorResponseProperty{
                         ErrorCode = 404,
                         ErrorCachingMinTtl = 30,
                         ResponseCode = 200,
                         ResponsePagePath = "/index.html"
                     },
                     new CustomErrorResponseProperty{
                         ErrorCode = 405,
                         ErrorCachingMinTtl = 30,
                         ResponseCode = 200,
                         ResponsePagePath = "/index.html"
                     }
                 }

            };


            new CloudFrontWebDistribution(this, "theDistribution", webDistributionProps);
```

Am I missing something?

Answer (score 1):

To save some time for whoever is googling the same things I was.
Opened a bug in GitHub and got a response:

It looks like this is a known issue with jsii, the underlying multi-language tech behind the CDK. See aws/jsii#1029 for more details.

The short answer is the sub-classing can work, but you need to extend from Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase as well as the interface:

```
public class CustomErrorResponseProperty : Amazon.JSII.Runtime.Deputy.DeputyBase, CfnDistribution.ICustomErrorResponseProperty
{
    public double ErrorCode { get; set; }
    public double ErrorCachingMinTtl { get; set; }
    public double ResponseCode { get; set; }
    public string ResponsePagePath { get; set; }
}
```

https://github.com/aws/aws-cdk/issues/14897#issuecomment-854618984